# Bash: conditionally color output text

Tags: bash

So I'm working on a script where part of it is generating an array of files/directories, and printing them out for the user to confirm they've been selected right. I would like to color the directories differently than the files, like ls does.

Currently, here's how I'm outputting the data:

```
printf '  %q\n' "${files[@]}"
```

That works great. I know how to use color codes to change printf color output, I just don't know how to make it conditional.

To make matters a little easier, I'm using the -p flag to get the file output to begin with. So all directories will end with the / character. Again, I'm not just entirely sure how to write this particular kind of conditional logic, even thought I know there has to be a way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about declaring 2 variables that hold the format to use for files/directories, then loop over your list and `[ -d "$i" ] && printf "$colorfmt" "$i" || printf "$plainfmt" "$i"`?

Comment: `-d` seems more *expensive* that `[[ "$1" ~ */ ]]` ? (or whatever the exact shell match chars would be). Otherwise, great stuff! Post as an answer and I'll upvote. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
# input files
files=$(ls -p)

# array with formatted file names
formatted_files=()

# a few demo ANSI coloring codes
ANSI_RESET=$(tput sgr0)
ANSI_BOLD=$(tput bold)
ANSI_GREEN=$(tput setaf 2)

# iterate over input files, conditionally coloring
# and appending to formatted files array
for file in ${files[@]}; do
    if [[ "$file" =~ /$ ]]; then
        formatted_files+=("$ANSI_BOLD$file$ANSI_RESET")
    else
        formatted_files+=("$ANSI_GREEN$file$ANSI_RESET")
    fi
done

# output (directories bold, files green)
printf '  %q\n' "${formatted_files[@]}"
```

When iterating over files, we test for directories with bash regular expression matching operator within double brackets test expression. A file is a directory if it ends with a slash `/$`.

Note we use only bash internal/builtin commands for iterating and testing, so it should be as fast as possible for a pure bash solution.